# Generic Entity mapping in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-assembly

I want to make a generic entity mapper that maps all entities to dbContext and EF. Currently, after I do `Add-Migration init`, I receive an error:

```
Cannot create an instance of Models.DataMapping.EntityMapper`1[TEntity] because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true.
```

I do not understand what this error exacly means and why if type `ContainsGenericParameters` is true it should cause a crash. Any ideas what is wrong and how could I fix it?
This is my code:

```
namespace Models.DataMapping
{
    public interface IEntityMapper
    {
        void Map(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

```
namespace Models.DataMapping
{
    public abstract class EntityMapper<TEntity> : 
        IEntityMapper where TEntity : class
    {
        public void Map(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> entityTypeBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>();

            MapEntity(entityTypeBuilder);
        }

        protected virtual void MapEntity(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> entityTypeBuilder) 
        {    
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Models.DataMapping
{
    public static class EntityMappersProvider
    {
        public static IReadOnlyCollection<IEntityMapper> GetLocalEntityMappers() {
            return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(t => typeof(IEntityMapper).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.IsClass)
                .Select(t => (IEntityMapper)Activator.CreateInstance(t))
                .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Including provider in dbContext.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            IReadOnlyCollection<IEntityMapper> entityMappers = EntityMappersProvider.GetLocalEntityMappers();

            foreach (IEntityMapper mapper in entityMappers) {
                mapper.Map(modelBuilder);
            }
        }
```

Example of Entity relationships realization.

```
namespace Models.DataMapping.EntitiesMapping
{
    public class CourseMapper : EntityMapper<Course>
    {
        protected override void MapEntity(EntityTypeBuilder<Course> entityTypeBuilder)
        {
            entityTypeBuilder.ToTable("Courses");
            entityTypeBuilder.HasKey(a => a.Id);
            //....
        }
    }
}
```

Also what I have noticed that if I remove `abstract` keyword in `EntityMapper` and add `t.IsAbstract` in `EntityMappersProvided` empty migration gets created..

Comment: Why are you doing this? What do you mean by "maps entities to dbcontext and EF"? Entity Framework provides your DBContext... and using runtime mapping (like Automapper) means you lose compile-time type-safety.

Comment: Instead of mapping every entities parameters and relationships in OnModelCreating method in db context I want to have a separation and configure every entity separate by implementing this mapper class

Comment: looks like you're trying to re-invent a built-in wheel, we already have `ModelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration` to apply a separate configuration specified in a class implementing `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>`

Comment: What do you mean by "entities parameters"? Entities don't have parameters - they're types, not methods.

Comment: properties, my bad..

Comment: So, your idea is to do configuration in separate places rather than inline in `OnModelCreating`. This is a good idea, but you are trying to invent/create something which already has a solution. But I'm assuming you didn't know about this. The solution is `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` interface. Here is an [example](IEntityTypeConfiguration)

Comment: Thanks, founded what I need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it looks like you are trying to reinvent [`IEntityTypeConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/#grouping-configuration) which allows to move entity configuration code to separate classes :

```
public class BlogEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Blog>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Blog> builder)
    {
        builder
            .Property(b => b.Url)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

And provides convenience method to find all such configuration in assembly, which is available since [EF Core 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.applyconfigurationsfromassembly?view=efcore-5.0#applies-to):

```
modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(BlogEntityTypeConfiguration).Assembly);
```

As for your error - it happens because your code tries to instantiate an open generic type (`EntityMapper<TEntity>`) with `Activator.CreateInstance`:

```
public class OpenGeneric<T>{}
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(OpenGeneric<>)); // throws Cannot create an instance of Generic`1[T] because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true.
```

So you need to filter it out, for example by adding `&& !t.IsAbstract && ! t.ContainsGenericParameters` in your `Where` clause.